# Creating an Active Directory login with specified SID

Tags: logins, domain

I have restored (FULL) a database using SSMS to a new server. When I did this we received errors indicating the account was unable to login, likely due to bad SID as we confirmed the account did transfer during the restore and had appropriate permissions. We have tried deleting and re-adding the user through the GUI of SSMS and receive the same login errors from our application (user does not exist). To fix this, the only solution I can find is to specify creating the login with a specific SID as the query below shows. When I execute this, SQL Server appears to have a problem with the "" in the domain. I cannot find another way to specify this that works. Am I missing syntax? How does one go about making an AD service account login with a specified SID if the syntactical "" is not accepted?

```
CREATE LOGIN [AD_DOMAIN\login]
WITH PASSWORD = 'password_here', SID = SID_HERE;

SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'AD_DOMAIN\login';
GO
```

At this point it would be easier to just create a brand new service account in AD, but inquiring here to see if I am missing something stupid....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restore the db to a new server, you also need to migrate the logins to the destination server. Here's what you can do to correctly remap the logins:

**Option 1:** The quickest way is to use the "transfer login" method from Microsoft, the old-school method. using the stored proc [`sp_help_revlogin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances). Carefully read and follow the article, as it will guide you on how to transfer the logins. The article also includes a link on [how to troubleshoot orphan users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).

**Option 2:** Install [`dbatools`](https://dbatools.io/). This is a community PowerShell module designed for SQL Server db migration, though it offers much more than just that. I recommend checking it out. Instructions for manual installation can be found on the website. Once installed, you can use the [`Copy-DbaLogin`](https://docs.dbatools.io/Copy-DbaLogin) command to transfer all or specific logins. There's a parameter called `-NewSid` which can generate new SIDs on the destination server — this is useful when copying logins onto the same server. The [`Repair-DbaDbOrphanUser`](https://docs.dbatools.io/Repair-DbaDbOrphanUser.html) can remap and fix the login mismatch.   **This is my preferred option.**

**Option 3:** As you mentioned, another option is to remove the login and recreate it. *I don't recommend this option.*

For a quick fix, use [sp_help_revlogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances). However, I highly recommend investing time in exploring the full range of capabilities that [`dbatools`](https://dbatools.io/) offers. Doing so will undoubtedly yield significant benefits in the long run, ensuring seamless db operations and ease of management.

Comment: DbaTools `Repair-DbaDbOrphanedUser` automatically repairs orphaned users https://docs.dbatools.io/Repair-DbaDbOrphanUser.html

Comment: @Charlieface thanks dbatools is very powerful. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @DanCo Thank you for the help and verbose explanations! I was familiar with DBA Tool backups but not other features. I tested the Copy-DbaLogin and it resolved our issues simply and quickly. I clearly need some more time to understand this process and solutions related to it. I'll continue to read more about the links you've mentioned

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing syntax?

Yes. Check type of the login by querying sys.database_principals
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

If the type is 'G' or 'U' you should create login as

```
CREATE LOGIN [AD_DOMAIN\login] from windows
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Only if the type is 'S' SQL user you should provide the password or SID

Comment: I appreciate the response. Unfortunately I needed to specify an SID, otherwise the command you mentioned does not work fully. The solution ended up being DBA Tools, or other commands to reconcile orphaned users. Without the SID specification, our app connections fail despite the user existing as created by your syntax. There could be specifics involved related to SID that I don't understand, but for now I have a solution that works consistently and an updated process to avoid this.

Comment: What is the type of login in sys.database_principals : SQL server 'S' or windows ones 'G' or 'U'?

Comment: The type of login is U. It is a Windows Domain User Account. The problem with the suggestion you provided is that it can indeed create the user. I had already tried your syntax before asking the original question. Unfortunately, when trying to assign permissions and/or make app connections using the account, we receive an error from SQL Server indicating the account does not exist. This is not a syntax issue, but rather an issue with an SID that was transferred and mixed up in SQL Server. In any case, DBA Tools copy-login reconciled that issue and I will use that going forward.